# How to solve "addEventListener" TypeError of null in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, model-viewer

I am trying to use Google's model viewer to load 3D models. It has a button. But I want that button to be visible after the model is completely loaded. So, I used to use this Vanilla JavaScript code

```
<script>
   const modelViewer = document.querySelector("model-viewer");
   const button = document.getElementById("my_ar_button");

   modelViewer.addEventListener("load", function() {
   button.style.display = "block";
   });
</script>
```

Now I am planning to use it in ReactJS and this is what it looks like

```
const modelViewer = document.querySelector("model-viewer");
const button = document.getElementById("my_ar_button");
    
modelViewer.addEventListener("load", function() {
button.style.display = "block";
});

<model-viewer 
src="https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/reflective-sphere.gltf"
alt="A 3D model of an astronaut"
ar ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look"
ar-scale="auto"
quick-look-browsers="safari chrome"
ios-src="https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.usdz"
loading="eager"
poster="https://modelviewer.dev/assets/poster-astronaut.png"
autoplay
camera-controls
>
  <button id="my_ar_button" class="my_ar_button" slot="ar-button">Show AR</button>
</model-viewer>
```

My CSS

```
.my_ar_button {
display: none;
}
```

I have added model-viewer using script tag

```
<Helmet>
 <script
 type="module"
 src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"
 async
 >
 </script>
</Helmet>
```

But it is giving me this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Comment: Make use of ```refs``` to access the DOM element. check useRef.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are a few details missing from your question that make it difficult to answer. Please can you show us how you import `model-viewer` into your project. Is it by script tag or via npm? You have provided some code, but no context. Where does that code run? In a component? If so, please show the code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control `<model-viewer>` element within a React wrapper. See [react-model-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-model-viewer), this is is their wrapper

```js
const useModelLoader = (type, src): ModelData => {
  const loader = useMemo(() => getLoader(type), [type]);

  const [model, setModel] = useState(undefined);
  const [modelCenter, setModelCenter] = useState<THREE.Vector3>(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    loader.load(
      // resource URL
      src,
      // called when the resource is loaded
      model => setModel(model),
      // called while loading is progressing
      ({ loaded, total }) => setProgress((loaded / total) * 100),
      // called when loading has errors
      error => setError(error)
    );
  }, [loader, src]);

  // get the center of the model
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!model) {
      return;
    }

    const box = new THREE.Box3();

    box.setFromObject(model.scene);

    const center = new THREE.Vector3();

    box.getCenter(center);

    setModelCenter(center);
  }, [model]);

  return { model, modelCenter, progress, error };
};
```

The 2nd `useEffect()` depends on `model`, so you can do the same with the button. This would be the React equivalent of `modelViewer.addEventListener("load", function() {`

```js
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (model) {                // when model has a value, the loader has completed
    setShowButton(true);      // now show the button
  }
}, [model]);

const Button = showButton ? <button...> : null;  // use this to wrap <button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it looks like `react-model-viewer` is not being maintained anymore. And `model-viewer` already has a event [Load](https://modelviewer.dev/docs/#entrydocs-loading-events-load)

Comment: It doesn't really matter that it's not maintained, the code I posted shows you how to integrate the non-react `model-viewer` component into the react way of working, including the load event (where is says `// called when the resource is loaded`).  Do you understand React components, if so the above should be enough to get you going.